# How to prevent Dropping a Dragged Item at Specific place/area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have implemented Drag and drop functionality on table cells, it is working fine for dragging and dropping, but am not able to show any prevention message or that circuler curson on dropping element if there is already have one elemnt, means in some cells i have a `<span></span>` tag and that is only am dragging and dropping and the rest of the cells are empty means not having `<span></span>` tag and am dragging and dropping that `<span></span>` at any of rest of empty cells in which there is no `<span></span>`,my html is as bellow
[This is the Output Snapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE9eI.png)

```
 <table border="1" class="display nowrap dataTable dtr-inline" id="example">
      <thead>
          <tr><th>Column Header</th><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th<th>Head3</th><th>Head4</th><th>Head5</th></tr>
   </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td class="name" id="1_undefined">Head1</td><td class="alertShow" id="1_0"></td><td class="alertShow" id="1_1"></td><td class="alertShow" id="1_2"></td><td class="alertShow" id="1_3"></td><td class="alertShow" id="1_4"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="name" id="2_10">Head2</td><td class="alertShow" id="2_1"></td><td class="displaydata"><span id="id_2_2" class="booked" draggable="true"></span></td><td class="alertShow" id="2_3"></td><td class="alertShow"><span id="id_2_4" class="booked" draggable="true"></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
    <td class="name" id="3_10">Room3</td><td class="alertShow" id="3_0"></td><td class="alertShow" id="3_1"></td><td class="alertShow" id="3_2"></td><td class="alertShow" id="3_3"></td><td class="alertShow" id="3_4"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

and this is my script code this code is not allow to drop duplicate elements,but want to show some preventon message and am not able to do that

```
 $('.booked').on("dragstart", function (event) {
            $(this).closest('td').removeClass("displaydata")
            $(this).closest('td').addClass("alertShow")
            var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));        
        });

        $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.type === 'drop') {
                var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
                if($(this).find('span').length===0){
                    var de=$('#'+data).detach();
                    de.appendTo($(this));   
                        $(this).closest('td').removeClass("alertShow");
                        $(this).closest('td').addClass("booked");                    
                }

            };

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for innerhtml of the cell in which you are trying do drop the cell

```
if ($(this).html() === '') {
//apped content
}
```

Here is full code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.booked').on("dragstart", function (event) {
                $(this).closest('td').removeClass("displaydata")
                $(this).closest('td').addClass("alertShow")
                var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
            });

            $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (event.type === 'drop') {
                    var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
                    if ($(this).html() === '') {
                        var de = $('#' + data).detach();
                        de.appendTo($(this));
                        $(this).closest('td').removeClass("alertShow");
                        $(this).closest('td').addClass("booked");
                    }

                }
                ;

            });
        })
```

Comment: actually i forgot to menstion in question that the code is not let the drop that element if the element is already there,what i want to do is just show some message or that black circle on the cursor if if we are trying to drop event at wrong destination

Comment: Then you can use use some notification /alert in your if block what is the problem with that

Comment: i tried some approaches but none of them worked,like checkking th class,comparing Id's but that didn't worked
i tried something like
if($(this).closest('td').hasClass("booked"))
                    {
                        alert("You Can Not Drop This Element here.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).closest('td').removeClass("alertShow");
                        $(this).closest('td').addClass("booked");   
                    }

Comment: Resolved the issue,by simply placing else condition on my original code

Answer (score 1):

```
     $('.booked').on("dragstart", function (event) {
                $(this).closest('td').removeClass("displaydata")
                $(this).closest('td').addClass("alertShow")
                var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
                dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));        
            });

        $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
           event.preventDefault();
           if (event.type === 'drop') {
           var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
               if($(this).find('span').length===0){
                  var de=$('#'+data).detach();
                  de.appendTo($(this));   
                  $(this).closest('td').removeClass("alertShow");
                  $(this).closest('td').addClass("booked");                    
               }
             else{
                   alert("You can not Put this item here");
                 }
           };

      });
```